# Trying to create my first Angular project using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I have installed npm and Angular CLI, which created the package.json file in folder "C:\Users\meast\source\repos\angularproject1". However, when I try to create a new Angular project in Visual Studio I keep getting the error "Could not find file C:\Users\meast\source\repos**angularproject2**\package.json", or when I try to extend the project I get "Could not find file C:\Users\meast\source\repos**angularproject1**\package.json"  even though it is there.

Comment: check the file permissions

Comment: If you create an Angular project in VS 2022, you don't need to use Angular CLI directly.

Comment: But then why is VS telling me it can't find the "package.json" file while creating the project, even though it exists?

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault, instead of choosing "ASP.NET Core with Angular" I chose the wrong project type. This can be closed.